# Azure AD B2C - Reject Passwords with name, surname, username

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, entra

I would like to know if it's possible in Azure AB B2C to reject passwords that contain the user's first name, last name, given name, username and possibly dictionary words. I have followed and implemented the instructions for setting up a custom password validator in the policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/password-complexity?pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively supported by the B2C tenant configuration or policy configuration but it is possible using a `ValidationTechnicalProfile` and a custom REST API.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          ...
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- claims to be collected from the user -->
            ...

          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidatePassword" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidatePassword">
          <DisplayName>Validate user input data and return loyaltyNumber claim</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-app.azurewebsites.net/api/ValidatePassword</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Your API then does the custom password checks such as

```cs
if (request.Password.Contains(request.givenName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
      return {{ b2c 409 response }};
```

See [REST API validation error response message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message)

Comment: It does not look like Azure B2C gives you the password in the claims

Comment: Password claims are only scoped to the technical profile and validation technical profiles it is collected in. You are correct in saying you cannot access the password outside of the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLoginEmail` orchestration step, therefore you must do it inside the Technical Profile as a Validation Technical Profile. I've implemented this for almost all of our clients so if you're having issues it might be best posting the code that you've tried and debugging from there.